# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping when migrating from java8 to java11

Tags: java, spring

I'm getting following error when migrating project from java8 to java11, spring4 to spring5.3.16

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping
        at ai.foremast.micrometer.web.servlet.HandlerMappingIntrospector.initHandlerMappings(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:166)
        at ai.foremast.micrometer.web.servlet.HandlerMappingIntrospector.<init>(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:83)
        at ai.foremast.micrometer.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.init(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:95)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4608)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5258)
```

Spring dependencies in pom:

```
<spring.version>5.3.17</spring.version>
```

...

```
 <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>
```

...

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: According to the javadocs, that class is present in 5.3.17.  So this is probably an issue with the dependencies.  Have you tried using the Spring "BOM" dependency?  See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-maven-bom

Comment: (I don't understand the reason for the exclusions in your POM.  Are they necessary?  What do they achieve?  You seem to be including the dependency on "spring-core" explicitly, then excluding the same dependency where ever it appears transitively ...)

Comment: @StephenC, yes, agreed on exclusions. its old code. cleaned it up. pom updated. 
Even after adding `spring-framework-bom` getting same exception.

Comment: Am I missing to add any spring dependency?

Comment: I can't tell.  Take a look at what is actually in your WAR file.

Comment: Spotted a problem.  You are missing a dependency on spring-webmvc

Comment: For some reason, the lib is present while compiling, but missing while running. Anyway, you are stuck, If possible delete the m2 folder and synch one more time.

Comment: yes, adding spring-webmvc worked! (gave me some other error now :) progress!) Please add it as an answer for me to accept.